# How work with entity inheritance in Spring Boot 2 application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm creating an application using Spring Boot 2. The application works with claims from persons, organisations and individual entrepreneurs. All the claims have a common set of fields: number, date, department and etc. There is only 1 part that is different for the claims - information about an applicant. Such information is very different for different kinds of applicants: passport for person, bank account  for organisation and etc.

Data is stored in the database, I use Spring Data and it's OK.

I cannot understand what is the best way to create DTO for creating, editing and reading the claims. Also there is one more question: use entity inheritance or not?

Let's begin with the 2nd part. The 1st variant is to create base class with common fields and to store applicants data in derived classes.

```
public class Claim {
    private String number;
    private Date date;
}

public class PersonClaim extends Claim {
    private Person person;
}

public class CorporativeClaim extends Claim {
    private Corporation corporation;
}
```

And the 2nd variant is to use composition:

```
public class Claim {
    private String number;
    private Date date;
    private Person person;
    private Corporation corporation;
}
```

I'm not sure but the 1st variant seems to be better.

Problem with DTOs is the same. Variant 1:

```
public class ClaimCreationDTO {
    private String number;
    private Date date;
}

public class PersonClaimCreationDTO extends ClaimDTO {
    private Person person;
}

public class CorporativeClaimCreationDTO extends ClaimDTO {
    private Corporation corporation;
}
```

REST controller's methods can either accept deserialized objects of base class (using json subtypes) or objects of derived class (separate method for each class)

Variant 3:

```
public class ClaimCreationDTO {
    private String number;
    private Date date;
    private Person person;
    private Corporation corporation;
    private ApplicantType type;
}
```

There i'd choose the 1st variant but is has several issues:

1. I require new controller method for each claim type or using subtypes. What is better?
2. If I use entity inheritance and DTO inheritance and send for example PersonalClaimEditDTO with id of the corporative claim what should I do?

What solution for this problem is preferred?

Comment: 2nd variation (composition) seems to be not correct. You should still have `PersonClaim` and `CorporativeClaim` and `Claim` as a field in them, if you really mean composition.

Comment: Also in your 2nd variation, you need to add new fields if new claims has to be added in the future. In addition, I guess it can only be one of the claim types at the same time. So other claim columns should effectively be `null`. This situation would add additional logic complexity into your code.

Comment: @humbaba and what about the 1st variant? How would you do?

Comment: Well, it really depends. There are several inheritance strategies in JPA. Depending on if you want polymorphic queries, also depending on the size and depth of your inheritance hierarchy, you can select one of those strategies. You can take a look at here: https://thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/